# Call 'hasOwnProperty' on a reponse (fetch-api)

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch, hasownproperty

I know this is kinda dumb/useless, but I would love to understand it. I tried to call `hasOwnProperty` on a response-object but it always returns `false`. Why?

```
(await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')).hasOwnProperty('status');
```

Comment: The simplest use of fetch() takes one argument — the path to the resource you want to fetch — and returns a promise containing the response (a Response object).

This is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json() method (defined on the Body mixin, which is implemented by both the Request and Response objects.)

Comment: @JessicaBulldog why post this as a comment and not just add it to your answer? Code only answers discouraged

Comment: (await (await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')).json())..hasOwnProperty('status') which returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, at least, the `status` property is not actually an own-property, but a *getter* on the prototype:

```js
fetch('https://stacksnippets.net/js', { mode: 'no-cors' })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(
      response.hasOwnProperty('status'),
      Object.getPrototypeOf(response).hasOwnProperty('status'),
      Object.getPrototypeOf(response) === Response.prototype
    );
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Response.prototype, 'status'));
  });
```

So by referencing `response.status`, you'll be invoking the getter, despite the fact that the response does not have `status` as an own-property.

Error objects in some environment behave the same way - in earlier versions of Firefox, for example, the `.message` property is a property of `Error.prototype`, rather than being an own property of the error instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.hasOwnProperty('status')));
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps